# How to use Prototypal Pattern to make an html5 rectangle for reuse

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to understand Prototypal Inheritance using the Prototypal pattern by making a rectangle object and an instance of the rectangle. Seems easy, but I'm not getting it. The RectanglePrototype's method is not drawing the rectangle onto the canvas. If I use the same function as the method it works. Where am I going wrong? Also, I understand that I will need to make an initialization function, but I'm thinking I can do that later after I get the first basic steps down.

**javascript:**

```
    window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var RectanglePrototype = {
        // Properties
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: "white",

        // Method
        get:function (x, y, width, height, color) {
            context.translate(0 , 0);
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(x, y, width, height);
            context.fillStyle = color;
            context.fill();
            return this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.color;
        }
    };

    console.log(RectanglePrototype.get);

    // Instance of RectanglePrototype
    var rectangle1 = Object.create(RectanglePrototype);
        rectangle1.x = 200;
        rectangle1.y = 100;
        rectangle1.width = 300;
        rectangle1.height = 150; 
        rectangle1.color = '#DBE89B';

    // Draw Rectangle Function
    function rect(x, y, width, height, color) {
        context.translate(0 , 0);
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(x, y, width, height); // yLoc-canvas.height = -300
        context.fillStyle = color;
        context.fill();
    };

    rect(0, 450, 50, 50, '#F7F694');    

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prototypes are extensions of objects that result from a constructor. Method lookups go through the object properties before looking into prototype.

I proper JS design, you would only add the non-function properties in your constructor.

```
//Your constructor
function Rectangle(){
    // Properties
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 100;
    this.color = 'red';
}
```

And then put the methods in your prototype:

```
//I prefer the term 'draw'
Rectangle.prototype.draw = function(ctx){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
};
```

Then, to use in your project:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//List of your shapes to draw on the canvas
var shapes = [];

//Instance of Rectangle
var rectangle1 = new Rectangle();
    rectangle1.x = 200;
    rectangle1.y = 100;
    rectangle1.width = 300;
    rectangle1.height = 150; 
    rectangle1.color = '#DBE89B';
    shapes.push(rectangle1);

//Draw your shapes
function draw(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);    //See MDN for proper usage, but always request next fram at the start of your draw loop!

    for(var i = 0; i<shapes.length; i++){
        shapes[i].draw(context);
    }
}
```

This is the 'proper' way of drawing to the canvas. For anything larger scale, please look into existing engines that do a looooot of hard work for you and have thought of everything so you don't have to. I have worked on such engines.

Comment: thank you for your response, but it seems you are using the classical model and I'm trying to understand the prototypal model or pattern. Yes, most likely I would use an engine or library in the future. I'm just trying to get an understanding of javascript.

Comment: @milkIt no he isn't; what makes you say that?

Comment: @Mathletics, I don't know javascript that well and I see the new keyword which I thought was reserved for classical model, and I don't see ojbect.create(). As mentioned, I'm learning and may very well be wrong.

Comment: Not only functions are looked up on the prototype, all properties are! And you can as well create non-function properties on the prototype, it's not bad habit!

Comment: @milkIt: Mathletics *is* using the Prototypal pattern. The fact that object prototypes are used in your code and Mathletic's code means both are implmentations of Prototypal inheritance. JavaScript can't use classical inheritance because the language doesn't have classes. It only has Constructor functions and Prototypes.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I didn't write any code, I think you mean Frederic Charette. In any case, yes, it's all prototype.

Comment: @milklt If you are looking to learn Javascript, I suggest you start doing your homework. Your question suggests that you haven't read about prototypes before posting, am I correct ?

Comment: @Bergi It is true. It can be useful for some specific cases. But that's for another class.

Comment: @Frederic Charette I appreciate the tip, and I have been reading about prototypes(this is [cool](http://www.objectplayground.com/)). I don't know what you are insinuating; however, I'm not expecting to become pro overnight, but eventually get better at Javascript. When I come to a problem I can not solve and have spent time on, I come here for help. Thank you for your help and your code write-up. It has taught me something new. Cheers!

Comment: @milklt Interesting link. I personally prefer Shelby Moore's approach to Javascript Inheritance: http://www.coolpage.com/developer/javascript/Correct%20OOP%20for%20Javascript.html